# How can I turn a global variable to a $this-> variable in php?

Tags: php

I want to turn a global variable in my function inside my class to a $this-> variable. Is this possible? this is the code I have for the class.

```
class tool  
{

 //If this is used remember to replace Void with $target

    public function mute()
    {

        global $target;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET mute='1' WHERE name='". $target ."'");

    }

}
```

Comment: see see code example: http://3v4l.org/p7oH4

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do it is to pass it as a parameter to your constructor and assign it to a member variable:

```
class Tool  
{
    protected $target;

    public function __construct($target)
    {
        $this->target = $target;
    }

    public function mute()
    {
        // Do stuff. I recommend not using mysql_*. Look into mysqli_* or PDO
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET mute='1' WHERE name='". $this->target ."'");
    }
}

$tool = new Tool($target);
```

Comment: Wow, I wrote the exact same code as you... that's interesting! I deleted my answer in favor of yours because you posted first.

Comment: @mc10 I guess that means we might be on to something! ;)

Comment: For some reason it didn't update the information in the database :l any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get the error, I did try to echo this though echo "Target: ".$this->target; and nothing showed up.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question, but why do this?  Just pass `$target` into `mute()` when you call it.  Unless your class is much more complex `$target` doesn't need to be a class var.

Comment: @M4TRIX are you sure `$target` has a value before you try to use it?

Comment: I could just use the global $target; but I am using $this->target; for practice since I always manage to forget how to use it and I am tyring to use it as much as possible.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm sure it has one because I am putting it in a text box and using the explode function on the text the making it a varible by doing this $target = $cmd[1]; since it is the second word

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
 * Please, read this too : http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS;hb=HEAD
 * 
 * Classes should be given descriptive names. Avoid using abbreviations where
 * possible. Each word in the class name should start with a capital letter,
 * without underscore delimiters (CamelCaps starting with a capital letter).
 * The class name should be prefixed with the name of the 'parent set' (e.g.
 * the name of the extension)::
 */
class Tool{

    private $target;

    public function __construct( $target ){
        $this->target = $target;
    }

    public function mute(){
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET mute='1' WHERE name='". $this->target ."'");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you want the value of `$this->target` to always match the `global $target` even if the global is later changed. Set a reference to the global $target when the class is initialized.

```
class tool  
{

    protected $target;        

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->target = &$GLOBALS['target'];
    }

    public function mute()
    {

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET mute='1' WHERE name='". $this->target ."'");

    }

}
```